# Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean to Error Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm extracting a `Boolean` from Firebase. However, I'm getting an the `Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean` error when I pull this data.

[image: Firebase Database]
How do I pull `Boolean` data?

```
List<Product> productList;
List<Boolean> productListStates;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.child("0").child("states").child("001");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Product p = snapshot.getValue(Product.class);
            productListStates.add(p.getStates());
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

**Product Class:**

```
public class Product {

    private String places;
    private String time;
    private String title;
    private String id;
    private boolean States;

    public Product(){
    }

    public Product(String places, String time, String title, String id, boolean States) {
        this.places = places;
        this.time = time;
        this.title = title;
        this.id = id;
        this.States = States;
    }

    public String getplaces() {
        return places;
    }

    public String gettime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String gettitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean getStates() {
        return States;
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the complete logcat and how you define your model class (Product). Share also how Product is defined/stored on firebase

Comment: I updated subject

Comment: Please add the structure of your database as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot amd please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Add firebase screen shot

Comment: Looking at your scheme under states there isn't a Product but only a boolean property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in your schema, under the `states` node there is no object of type `Product`, is only a property of type boolean. That's why you get that error. To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
final DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.child("0").child("states").child("001");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        booblean b = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(b));
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

}

The result in the logcat will be:

```
true
```